# FATAL EXCEPTION with AndroidNativeAudio and intersect.getBoundsInLocal() use

Tags: java, android, javafx, fatal-error, javafxports

The context:
A JavaFX video game for Android. Sometimes (from 5 to 20 minutes, depending on the game use), a FATAL EXCEPTION occurs.

```
D/AudioTrackShared(  317): front(0x1dd800), mIsOut 1, avail 0, mFrameCount 4096, filled 4096

D/AudioTrackShared(  317): front(0x1dd800), mIsOut 1, obtainBuffer() FUTEX_WAIT

E/AndroidRuntime(14369): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread

E/AndroidRuntime(14369): Process: com.gluonapplication, PID: 14369

E/AndroidRuntime(14369): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=-1

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1583)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1527)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1380)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:564)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1711)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2408)

E/AndroidRuntime(14369):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:348)
```

---

The main algorithm consists in detecting an intersection between two rectangles. And there are about 10 rectangles for detecting mutual intersections, in each periodical processing (110 ms). Therefore, the getBoundsInLocal Rectangle.intersect are very used (about 60 times) in 110ms
The code is:

```
     boolean bCollisionDetected = false;
     if (o1.equals(o2) == false) {

        double x1Min, x1Max, y1Min, y1Max;
        Bounds ivb1 = o1.getImageView().getBoundsInParent();
        x1Min = ivb1.getMinX();
        x1Max = ivb1.getMaxX();
        y1Min = ivb1.getMinY();
        y1Max = ivb1.getMaxY();

        double x2Min, x2Max, y2Min, y2Max;
        Bounds ivb2 = o2.getImageView().getBoundsInParent();
        x2Min = ivb2.getMinX();
        x2Max = ivb2.getMaxX();
        y2Min = ivb2.getMinY();
        y2Max = ivb2.getMaxY();

        if (((x2Min < x1Min) &&  (x1Min < x2Max)) || ((x2Min < x1Max) &&  (x1Max < x2Max)) 
                || ((y2Min < y1Min) &&  (y1Min < y2Max)) || ((y2Min < y1Max) &&  (y1Max < y2Max))) {
            // Suspicion de collision, on affine alors uniqt dans ce cas
            Rectangle rectangleP1 = o1.getEnveloppe();
            Rectangle rectangleP2 = o2.getEnveloppe();

//          intersect = Shape.intersect(rectangleP1, rectangleP2);
            intersect = Rectangle.intersect(rectangleP1, rectangleP2);
            bCollisionDetected = (intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1);           
        }       
     }
     return bCollisionDetected;
```

---

When I replace this code by checking the corners of the rectangles, there is no FATAL error, in the same use conditions, during a 5 hours test,as follows:

```
 boolean bCollisionDetected = false;

 if (!o1.equals(o2)) {
    NbRechercherImpactEntre++;
    double x1Min, x1Max, y1Min, y1Max, x1Milieu, y1Milieu;
    Bounds ivb1 = o1.getImageView().getBoundsInParent();
    x1Min = ivb1.getMinX();
    x1Max = ivb1.getMaxX();
    y1Min = ivb1.getMinY();
    y1Max = ivb1.getMaxY();
    x1Milieu = (x1Min + x1Max)/ 2;
    y1Milieu = (y1Min + y1Max) / 2;

    double x2Min, x2Max, y2Min, y2Max, x2Milieu, y2Milieu;
    Bounds ivb2 = o2.getImageView().getBoundsInParent();
    x2Min = ivb2.getMinX();
    x2Max = ivb2.getMaxX();
    y2Min = ivb2.getMinY();
    y2Max = ivb2.getMaxY();

    x2Milieu = (x2Min + x2Max) / 2;
    y2Milieu = (y2Min + y2Max) / 2;
    boolean b1 = (((x2Min < x1Min) &&  (x1Min < x2Max)) || ((x2Min < x1Max) &&  (x1Max < x2Max)))
            && (((y2Min < y1Min) &&  (y1Min < y2Max)) || ((y2Min < y1Max) &&  (y1Max < y2Max)));
    boolean b2 = (((x1Min < x2Min) &&  (x2Min < x1Max)) || ((x1Min < x2Max) &&  (x2Max < x1Max)))
            && (((y1Min < y2Min) &&  (y2Min < y1Max)) || ((y1Min < y2Max) &&  (y2Max < y1Max)));
    boolean b1Milieu = ((x2Min < x1Milieu) &&  (x1Milieu < x2Max)) && ((y2Min < y1Milieu) &&  (y1Milieu < y2Max)) ;
    boolean b2Milieu = ((x1Min < x2Milieu) &&  (x2Milieu < x1Max)) && ((y1Min < y2Milieu) &&  (y2Milieu < y1Max));


    if (b1 || b2 || b1Milieu || b2Milieu){
        bCollisionDetected = true;
    }
```

---

But there is also an audio algorithm using the AndroidNativeAudio class (Gluon for Android).

Question: 
- have you an idea of the problem origin (intersect or audio)

SOLVED - The solution is a memory leak problem:
In fact, the problem was: a File must be closed after its opening. That must be applied too in Audio management, otherwise there is a memory leak. In pratice, do that,in Android Native Audio: afd = FXActivity.getInstance().getAssets().openFd(this.audioFileNa‌​me); ..... **afd.close();** // used for the garbage collector –

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "checking the corners of the rectangles"? Can you post some code for that as well?

Comment: José: here are additional information about traces.I hope that they can help you

Comment: It looks like you have the same issue as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292122/fatal-exception-audiotrackshared-and-audioflinger-threads-causes-with-androidn) again? Basically you are creating a new Shape, and depending on the thread it is running, that might cause the issue. Can you try `rectangleP1.getBoundsInParent().intersects(rectangleP2.getBoundsInParent())` instead?

Comment: José:I am going to quickly try your solution, this evening. Do you mean that, when all rectangles and shapes are created in a Main and tested in a Timeline, that can involve an issue? If yes, I 'ld like to know the subtle reason. Thanks -  the"intersects method is about  local Bounds and not Parent ones. No pb about that? --- Note:  You write "same issue": it is true and sorry about that but the problem was not directly about the ArrayList use

Comment: About `intersects`, notice in my comment I get the bounds in parent first. The idea is to avoid creating shapes unnecessary that, at that high rate, could at some point lead to the exception you get "after several minutes" testing.

Comment: José: By using this code, there is no any FATAL exception but no any detected intersection. Do I correctly use the intersects method?  boolean bCollisionDetected = false;
  if (o1.equals(o2) == false) {     
   if (o1.getImageView().getBoundsInParent().intersects(o2.getImageView().getBoundsInParent())) {
    bCollisionDetected = (intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1);   
   }     
  }
  return bCollisionDetected;

Comment: Note that now you don't have `intersect` anymore. If both objects are children of the same parent, this should give you the collision indication: `bCollisionDetected = o1.getImageView().getBoundsInParent().intersects(o2.getImag‌​eView().getBoundsInP‌​arent());`.

Comment: Of course, a bad copy/paste :)

Comment: Are you using ImageView or Shape objects?

Comment: ImageView was only to optimize the real time against the intersect and boundsInLocal use because it minimized the number of intersect method call. With yous advice, I have simplified my algorithm by using what you wrote "getBoundsInParent", ImageView and "intersects". Now, I am testing this solution during several hours for ensuring there is no problem. and no any Shape and Rectangle are used.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remains the same. It seems to be a jdk problem, as mentions in Google results on keywords: "scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds". So, I open a new question

Comment: In fact, the problem was about that a File must be closed after its opening. That must be applied too in Audio management, otherwise there is a memory leak. In pratice, do that,in Android Native Audio:   afd = FXActivity.getInstance().getAssets().openFd(this.audioFileName);
.....   afd.close(); // used for the garbage collector

Comment: Nice catch. How did you find it? Profiling?

Comment: José: By setting the Java compiler options in "Errors/warnings": "resource leak" and "potential resource leak" to "Error". Eclipse directly points out the problem

Comment: We can't keep going adding different issues over comments. Please post a new question.